# CakePHP extending model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakePHP to develop small webpage and trying to graps MVC concept.

I have controller, in which action I am retrieving post with specified ID.

```
$post = $this->Post->findById($id);
```

I need to retrieve post title, concatenated with it's id - but I don't wanna do it in controller directly.
Of course I could write underneath $post['id'].','.$post['title'], because $post is an array.
But this will be needed in many places. Can I extend model somehow to achieve method to do it?

My approach was:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public function getTitleWithId() {
        return $this->id.','.$this->title;
    }
}
```

But as I saw model object is not exactly last fetched object.

Maybe I just need to create PostEntity object that accepts in constructor an array returned by findById? But maybe there is better solution.

Comment: You should update your question with your actual intentions, stuff like that you want to slugify the title before concatenation is important and should be in your question! ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CakePHP, `Model` class are manager, not really instance of a `Model` (even if the `id` is stored in). You could simply pass the `id` to your method and return what you want:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Post' ;
    public function getTitleWithId($id) {
        $post = $this->read(null, $id) ;
        return $post[$this->name]['id'].','.$post[$this->name]['title'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that approach too. So using that approach if I would really like some fancy object I could create factory method for that object in my model. If no one will come up with anything different I will mark your answer as solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is right: let all the data managing be in the model.

Although, take a look to **Virtual Fields**. It will do your concatenating easier:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Then you can do a find to your virtual field:

```
$this->Post->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => $id
    ),
    'fields' => array('yourVirtualField')
));
```

**EDIT**

Now that I've read again your question, probably you would need to do a **behavior**:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html

Think of that as a way to have *multiple inheritance* (not the same, but somewhat the idea goes along). You develop your method on it, and attach this behavior to only the models you need with:

```
public $actsAs = array('yourBehavior');
```

Comment: In that case yes, but what I didn't mention is that I would kill two birds with one stone. I will also need perform some operations on data. More specific example is that I want "slugify" title before concatenation :) Nevertheless thanks for insight on virtual fields, in case of concatenation and other pure SQL operations it will make life easier.

Comment: Please see my edit. Seems that I didn't read carefully your question, lol

Comment: you can't pass virtual field in `fields` array, check the docs http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields

Comment: Actually maybe I wrote it not very clear way. I didn't mean that I will need that method in other Models, but rather in different methods in controller :) But still that exact method might be reusable! Thanks.

Comment: @Anilkumar Actually you can, you'll only run into problems in case you are referencing the virtual fields of an _associated_ model.

Comment: I misunderstood the line, thanks for the info @ndm :)

Comment: @Eagle I'd say they are more like mixins or pseudo multiple inheritance, but definitely not interfaces ;)

Comment: @ndm well, now that you say it, it's more like multiple inheritance than interface :P I'll fix it.